# Connecting to as400 JDBC on Play Framework

Tags: java, jdbc, playframework, ibm-midrange

I'm having issues making a connection to an AS400 database inside of Play!.

My `application.conf` looks like:

```
db.default.driver="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver"
db.default.url="jdbc:as400://SERVER;libraries=A,B,C;toolbox trace=all;trace=true"
db.default.username="user"
db.default.password="password"
```

I've set up jt400 in the classpath, and I can see under "external libraries" that it shows up and is available. But essentially I get an error message about failing to connect (on user/password I know works) and failure to `execute isValid()`, which is a function that can not be found inside of `AS400JDBCConnection` class.

```
[error] c.z.h.p.PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Failed to execute isValid() for connection, configure connection test query. (com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnection.isValid(I)Z)
[error] application - 

! @72265nf0a - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
    at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:154)
    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:806)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:48)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi.connect(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get$lzycompute(DBModule.scala:72)
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get(DBModule.scala:62)
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get(DBModule.scala:58)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
Caused by: play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Failed to initialize pool: com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnection.isValid(I)Z]
    at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:154)
    at play.api.PlayConfig.reportError(Configuration.scala:996)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:70)
    at play.api.db.PooledDatabase.createDataSource(Databases.scala:199)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource$lzycompute(Databases.scala:123)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource(Databases.scala:121)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:142)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:138)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:44)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnection.isValid(I)Z
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:512)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:105)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:71)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool$$anonfun$1.apply(HikariCPModule.scala:58)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool$$anonfun$1.apply(HikariCPModule.scala:54)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:54)
    at play.api.db.PooledDatabase.createDataSource(Databases.scala:199)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource$lzycompute(Databases.scala:123)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource(Databases.scala:121)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnection.isValid(I)Z
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.checkDriverSupport(PoolBase.java:400)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.setupConnection(PoolBase.java:375)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:346)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:506)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:105)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:71)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool$$anonfun$1.apply(HikariCPModule.scala:58)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool$$anonfun$1.apply(HikariCPModule.scala:54)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:54)
```

I'm able to connect in other java-based projects using something like:

```
try {
                Class.forName("com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:as400://" + 
                    ApplicationAuthentication.server + "/" + 
                    ApplicationAuthentication.library, 
                    ApplicationAuthentication.user, 
                    ApplicationAuthentication.password
                );
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e);
                throw new WebApplicationException(genericError, Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
```

Comment: Sounds like that JDBC driver is JDBC 3 or older, the `Connection.isValid(int)` method was added in Java 6 / JDBC 4.

Comment: Is there a way to find what version of Java/JDBC jt400 uses? Having a hard time finding out.

Comment: Ask IBM, read the accompanying documentation? I don't use AS/400 so I have no idea.

Comment: A recent version of [jt400](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/toolbox/index.html) users JDBC 4. I've got Java 8 set up in my environment.

Comment: That you have Java 8 doesn't mean anything. A JDBC 3 driver (or even 1 or 2 if you can find them) will work under Java 8, as long as you don't call any methods defined in later JDBC versions (this applies to Java in general BTW, you can use a class compiled against an earlier version of an interface, with a newer version of that interface as long as you don't call the methods defined in that newer version of the interface).

Comment: Thanks for the info, Mark. Can't upvote. I keep running into walls with this aged data system and it looks like I simply will continue to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guessing from the stacktrace, it appears that the connection returned from your driver is not playing well with the connection [Hikari Connection Pool](https://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/). Hikari is [default connection pool in playframework](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SettingsJDBC).

Specifically, your exception trace shows that the Hikari CP is attempting to call `isValid` method on the connection object returned by your JDBC driver and then failing with `java.lang.AbstractMethodError`.

You can try switching to BoneCP connection pool and see if it helps. You can also check comments on [this issue](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/421) on hikari github issue list

Comment: Perfect! The option of multiple connection pools (and easily setting on inside of `application.conf`) was exactly what I needed. Simply adding a `play.db.pool=bonecp` was exactly what was necessary.

Comment: @Shawn please eleborate your solution

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to application.config

db.default.hikaricp.connectionTestQuery="SELECT 1"

Not tested in Play Framework but I had similar issue on spring framework and solved in that way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use liquibase datasource like below with connection-test-query

```
@Bean
    @LiquibaseDataSource
    public DataSource liquibaseDataSource() {
         HikariDataSource dataSource = (HikariDataSource) DataSourceBuilder.create().url("url")
                        .username("username")
                        .password("password")
                        .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
        dataSource.setConnectionTestQuery("select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1");
        return dataSource;
    }
```